# new JFrame over a Fullscreen Application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I'm testing a java Application in Fullscreen Mode, the fullscreen works fine, but when the user presses a button I want to display a new `JFrame` in the middle of the `Fullscreen` (it has to be a `JFrame`, not a `JDialog`) and this is what I do to call it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    Object source = ev.getSource();

    if (source == refresh) {
        // refresh
    } else {
        if (source == plan) {
            //plan
            final JFrame dialog = new JModificaciones();
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            // exit button
            device.setDisplayMode(originalDM);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

However this makes my Fullscren Application to get out of view and my new `JFrame` with another application as background (for example Mozilla), and I want my `JFrame` to appear ON TOP of my Fullscreen Application.

Comment: *"(it has to be a `JFrame`, not a `JDialog`)"*  Why?  Are you aware of `JDeskTopPane`/`JInternalFrame`?

Comment: A `JInternalFrame` is a good alternative, but if I use it, then I'd have to change my Fullscreen Application and pack everything inside a `JDesktopPane`, which would make the window's status bars visible.
At least that's what I could grasp from the `JDesktopPane` and `JInternalFrame` tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a external JFrame with fullscreen property and inside of it you can put JInternalFrames with center allignment so you don't need to use JDialog

Comment: Is it possible to skip the creation of a `JDesktopPane`? As far as I know any `JInternalFrame` must have a `JDesktopPane` as it's parent, or is there a way to create a non-visible `JDesktopPane` and put the new `JInternalFrame` on top of it?